# How to calculate the directional derivative of $f(x)=1/|x|$

Tags: calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I have the function $f:
\left(\Bbb{R}\setminus0\right)^n \to\mathbb{R}$ given that $n\ge 1$ defined by $$f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}$$ where $|x| = (x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{1/2}$.

I have to calculate the directional derivative in a generic $x\ne 0$ with the direction $v = \frac{\nabla f(x)}{|\nabla f(x)|}$.

Well, I verified that $f$ is differentiable $\forall x\ne 0$. Then the directional derivative is

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (x_0) = \left\langle \nabla f(x_0), \frac{\nabla f(x_0)}{|\nabla f(x_0)|}\right\rangle = \left|\nabla f(x_0)\right|$$

But now, if I have to calculate $|\nabla f(x_0)|$, how can I do it in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 3):

Well $\nabla f(x_0)=(\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_1 },\dots,\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_n })^T$ just by definition. So you just have evaluate all partial derivatives. In your case: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{1}{|x|}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{1}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{1/2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{3/2}}2x_i=\frac{-x_i}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{3/2}}$. So $\nabla f(x)=-\frac{1}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{3/2}}x$. Therefore $|\nabla f(x)|=\frac{1}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{3/2}}|x|=\frac{1}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})} $.